# Complex Bootstrap 2 Popovers Click to Dismiss

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have multiple unique popovers on a page, need to hide them when clicking anywhere but the popover current active. The popovers are a little more complex than the standard implementation, so what I know do to make them hide doesn't apply.

http://jsfiddle.net/bb37385m/

```
$('.popover-markup > .trigger').popover({
    html : true,
    title: function() {
      return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
    },
    content: function() {
      return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
    },
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'right'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you need to get your clicked element.

```
var objclass = $(event.target).attr('class');
```

We want the popup to disappear if clicked anywhere but itself. So we need to check if the click event is at anywhere on popup.

```
$(event.target).closest('.popover').length == 1
```

@bootstrap, to remove the popover use `.popover('hide');`

Result;

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
  var objclass = $(event.target).attr('class');
  if($(document).find('.popover').length > 0 && ($(event.target).closest('.popover').length == 1)){
      return false;
  }
  if ($(document).find('.popover').length > 0 && (objclass != 'trigger') && $(event.target).closest('.popover').length != 1) {
    $('.trigger').popover('hide');
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot! Now I just need to have only one popover open at a time...

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing to remember which pop up is currently active? It would be a good idea to add an `id` attribute to each of the `<div class="popover-markup">` elements.

You should bind a method to the `$('body')` element of the page, most probably `$('body').click();` is what you need. Make a new variable in that method, for example `$lastClicked` which remembers the `id` of the last clicked (or active) pop up.

Close the pop up with this `id` inside this method.